# Lock firebase firestore collection and write data + flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a scenario like this

when a user try to update a field "sample" in a collection :

- I have a check to see if the field is empty or not ..
- when the field is empty, update the field and show a toast message that the update is successful
- when the field is not empty just show a toast message that the update is failed

The issue I am facing is

When two user simultaneously updates the field (only milli seconds difference):

- User 1 gets the success message
- User 2 also gets the success message
- But only user 2's data is updated

I think the issue is because of the very less time difference. May be :

- when user 1 checks the field - its empty
- when user 2 checks the field - its empty as well
- user 1 updates the value
- user 2 also updates the value which overrides the user 1's value

Is there a way to lock update of the field when user 1 checks the field and updates it so that the user 2 cannot update the value in the same field

Here I have added the sample code :

```
    if (ownerId.isEmpty && equipmentId.isEmpty) {
         dm
            .assignBooking(
                bid: bid,
                status: 'approved',
                ownerId: uid,
                equipmentid: eid!,
                model: model,
                bookingType: notificationBookingType)
            .then((value) {
            if (value == true) {
            
              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                  msg: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                      .bookingsuccessfullyApproved,
                  timeInSecForIosWeb: 5);
            } else {
              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                  msg: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                      .bookingAcceptedBysomeoneElse,
                  timeInSecForIosWeb: 5);
            }


Future<bool> assignBooking({
required String bid,
required String status,
required String ownerId,
required String equipmentid,
required String model,
required String bookingType,
}) async {
// Fetch the existing booking data
var bookingData = await allBookings.doc(bid).get();

// Check if assigned_equipment_owner_id is empty
if (bookingData['assigned_equipment_owner_id'] == null ||
    bookingData['assigned_equipment_owner_id'].isEmpty) {
  // Update only if assigned_equipment_owner_id is empty
  await allBookings.doc(bid).update({
    "status": status,
    'assigned_equipment_owner_id': ownerId,
    'equipment_id': equipmentid,
    'model': model,
    'booking_type': bookingType,
  });
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
}
```

I am checking if the owner id and equipment id is null at two places before updating and showing the toast message. Still I am not able to handle the issue

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated the question with the code . Can you please check and help me with the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is related to a race condition, where two users are checking the condition (assigned_equipment_owner_id being empty) simultaneously, and both of them find it empty. Consequently, both users proceed to update the data, resulting in both getting a success message, but only one update is actually reflected in the database.

To handle this scenario, you need to implement a mechanism to ensure atomicity in the update operation, so that only one user can successfully update the data at a time.

One approach is to use a transaction to ensure that the check and update operations are treated as a single, atomic unit. This helps in avoiding race conditions where multiple users might try to update the data simultaneously.

```
Future<bool> assignBooking({
  required String bid,
  required String status,
  required String ownerId,
  required String equipmentid,
  required String model,
  required String bookingType,
}) async {
  try {

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      var bookingData = await allBookings.doc(bid).get();

      
      if (bookingData['assigned_equipment_owner_id'] == null ||
          bookingData['assigned_equipment_owner_id'].isEmpty) {
        transaction.update(allBookings.doc(bid), {
          "status": status,
          'assigned_equipment_owner_id': ownerId,
          'equipment_id': equipmentid,
          'model': model,
          'booking_type': bookingType,
        });
      } else {
        
        throw 'Equipment is already assigned to another owner.';
      }
    });

   
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you . Ill check and let you know if this works for my scenario

Comment: YOu can accept the answer if it helps.